# async/await nodejs funciontality

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have following code snippet with `async/await`.

```
async function test1 () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("1")
  }, 2000);
}

async function test2 () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("2")
  }, 1000);
}

async function test3 () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("3")
  }, 1500);
}

async function test4 () {console.log("4")}

async function run () {
  await test1()
  await test2()
  await test3()
  await test4()
}

run()
```

When I explore above code snippet, I am expecting output as 1, 2, 3, 4. But I got 4, 2, 3, 1. Am I missed anything here?

Node Version `v10.13.0`

Comment: You've missed the fact that you aren't doing anything awaitable, in any of those `async` functions, so they'll execute in the order of their timeouts (which looks correct).

Answer (score 5):

`await`ing `test1`, etc. is the same as `await`ing `setTimeout(...)` directly. `setTimeout` is not promise-based and isn't taken into account in promise chain.

`await test1()`, etc. result in one-tick delays, `run()` promise resolves instantly.

In order for the code to work as intended, it should be:

```
function test1 () {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("1");
    resolve();
  }, 2000));
}
```

`test1`, etc. don't need to be `async` because they cannot benefit from a promise created by `async` function.